# Why MediaStore is not updated when saving image to removable storage via SAF?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, mediastore, storage-access-framework, android-mediascanner

I try to move image file from my `getExternalFilesDir(null)` to **removable SD card**.
I used Storage Access Framework to get my access to SD card.

```
if (copy(context, sourceUri, targetUri)) return delete(context, sourceUri);
```

First I copy file to SD card and if it was copied successfully I remove original file from my sandbox.

```
public static boolean copy(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri sourceUri, @NonNull Uri targetUri) {
    InputStream inputStream = openInputStream(context, sourceUri);
    OutputStream outputStream = openOutputStream(context, targetUri);

    if (inputStream == null || outputStream == null) {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try { inputStream.close(); }
            catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }

        if (outputStream != null) {
            try { outputStream.close(); }
            catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
        return false;
    }

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I retrieve targetUri by calling this:

```
Uri targetUri = DocumentsContract.createDocument(context.getContentResolver(), destinationUri, mimeType, filename);
// targetUri is content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3A3A-11FB%3A/document/3A3A-11FB%3AIMG_2711.gif
```

File is **copied successfully**, but this file is never shown nor in Google Photos, nor when I query MediaStore myself. When I reboot device, everything is shown.

This is reproduced not on all devices, but on some, such as Mi A2 Lite on android 9.

I was thinking that content provider is responsible for updating all records for MediaStore.
Is there a way to update MediaStore myself?

`Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` and `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` dont work

**EDIT**: When I try to use getContentResolver().update() I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Update not supported` exception.

I try to update using following code:

```
final ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
vals.put(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, "testImage.jpg");
context.getContentResolver().update(targetUri, vals , null, null);
```

Interesting that `ContentValues` cannot be null, even though they are `@Nullable`. If they are `null` following exception will be raised:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.ContentValues.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:566)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1723)
        ...
```

`context.getContentResolver().refresh(targetUri, null, null);` also doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `OutputStream outputStream = openOutputStream(context, targetUri);` That you can open an output stream for a non existant file? Please give an example of the value of such an targetUri.toString(). How did you determine that uri?

Comment: @blackapps I edited my question to answer you

Comment: You can try to update the media store with getContentResolver(). update() using the File path. On Android Q you dont need SAF to place a file in the Documents or Download directory of the sd card.

Comment: @blackapps if I call getContentResolver().update(targetUri) I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Update not supported

Comment: The update() has three parameters. You cannot use your uri for the first parameter. The first paramrter should be the collection uri of your uri. After that make the where clause with the id of your uri.

Comment: @blackapps I think you don't understand my problem. I save file to a directory that I got when requesting STorage Access Framework (Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE). File is saved successfully to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3A3A-11FB%3A/document/3A3A-11FB%3AIMG_2711.gif . MediaStore doesn't know about this file until I restart my phone. What kind of "collection uri of your uri" are you talking about? Can you provide "collection uri" example for DocumentProvider?

Comment: So in your last comment you posted the saf uri of your file. Now show how you try to obtain the media store uri for this file. Put actions in your post please in the right sequence.

Comment: If you have a media store uri like content://media/external/images/media/12345 then the last segment is the id and all before it the collection.

Comment: Maybe im a bit confused by another post and mix things up. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779251/how-can-i-get-mediametadata-like-album-track-titel-albumart-etc-from-medias?noredirect=1#comment105703554_59779251

Comment: @blackapps I can't obtain MediaStore uri for this file because when I query MediaStore for all images, this file is not present. This reproduces only with removable SD card. If I save it to primary external storage then this file is found in MediaStore. If I save it to removable SD card and reboot device then this file appears (because MediaStore refreshes itself after reboot).

Comment: In which collection(s) do you find it after reboot?

Comment: @blackapps In the same I am searching for it before reboot: MediaStore.Images.Media

Comment: I realise now that you can not use MediaStore.getMediaUri() as that will only work if the file is already known by the media store. So what you have to do instead is using getContentResolver().insert() using the right relative or full path.

Comment: @blackapps the problem is that I should not use insert(). It'll create empty file in specific directory. I need it to be in root of removable sd card. After I copy it to root of sdcard on some devices this file appears in MediaStore, on some devices it doesnt. I think it's provider-specific behavior. DocumentsProvider should notify MediaStore about my file. And it does, most of the time. But not always. I need to refresh it, not to add record to it, because it will lead to multiple records if this file is already added to MediaStore

Comment: `It'll create empty file in specific directory. ` No. Not my expierience. And then you imply that your file is overwritten with that create. You did not mention that.

Comment: `DocumentsProvider should notify MediaStore about my file. ` Providers are not obliged to do that.

Comment: `I need to refresh it, not to add record to it, because it will lead to multiple records if this file is already added to MediaStore `. Well you can avoid that by first requesting a getMediaUri(). If it fails the file is not known by the media store yet. Otherwise use the uri.

Comment: @blackapps ```Providers are not obliged to do that```. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. In my experience its device specific. Too bad there in inconsistency in this behavior.

Comment: @blackapps anyway I will try your approach on monday. Seems like getMediaUri() should do the trick. If so, I will let you know, so you can post an answer and I will accept it. EDIT: oof, its available from api 29, but I reproduced this behaviour on android 7 and 9. Is there a way for older android versions?

Comment: @artman did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @Ljdawson no. I didnt find any workaround of fix for this

Comment: @artman damn, thanks for the update