# How can I get MediaMetaData like Album, Track, Title, Albumart, etc. from MediaStore in Android 10

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I struggled for a long time to fetch album, track, duration, album art from audiofiles using Android 10 `mediaStore`.

**What I did so far:**
Open an Intent an fetch the Audio-Folder:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose directory"), PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
```

Then `onActivityResult:`

```
mUri = data.getData();
childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(mUri));
```

Iterating through the cursor, I get the DocumentID from the audioFiles.

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(childrenUri, null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
     int idColumn = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DOCUMENT_ID);
     String documentId = c.getString(idColumn);
}
```

Then I open another cursor on the `mediaStore` to query audio columns;

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " like ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{documentId};
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor mediaCursor = resolver.query(mediaUri,null,null,null,null);
while (mediaCursor.moveToNext()) {
    int albumIndex = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
    String album = mediaCursor.getString(albumIndex);   
}
```

mediaUri: `content://media/external/audio/media`
documentUri: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/document/msf%3A23`

**Problem:**
My mediaCursor.getCount() = 0, so I can't fetch any results.
Whats wrong in my code so that I wasn't able to get e.g. albumName from `mediaStore`.

Thanks
GGK

Comment: The document id's of saf are different from those of the media store. But you could convert a saf uri first in a media store uri.

Comment: sounds logical, but where have do I set the convertedUri (`Uri convertedUri = MediaStore.getDocumentUri(mContext, documentUri);`? In my example I don't use the `selection` and `selectionArgs` Strings and got 0 results

Comment: No. Not getDocumentUri as you have already a document uri. Better: Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, documentUri);

Comment: `Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(mContext, documentUri);
                Cursor mediaCursor = resolver.query(mediaUri,null,null,null,null); so I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Missing volume name` error.

Comment: Can be. I just wrote this from memory. Investigate please. Im far from my computer. What was the value of mediaUri.toString() ?

Comment: the documentUri = `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/document/msf%3A23`and converting it via `Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(mContext, documentUri);` I got a file not found error

Comment: i'm sorry, made a copy&pase mistake: documentUri = `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/document/downloads` and mediaUri = `content://media/external/audio/media`

Comment: posted the Uris in the mainPost - sorry for the confusion

Comment: The media uri is invalid as it should end with the new media id. Your mefia uri is only the collection uri.

Comment: You are stil querying the media store with the saf document id. That will not go of course. Further you did not post the code where you obtained the document id.

Comment: Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                Uri convertedUri = MediaStore.getDocumentUri(mContext, documentUri);
                Cursor mediaCursor = resolver.query(convertedUri,null,null,null,null); building mediaCursoar failed with `Failed query: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No root for msf `

Comment: Split converted uri in collection uri and id. Then query collection for selection on id. You did not post the value of collectionUri.toString().

Comment: Can You explame more in detail...?

Comment: Its time you read al posts tagged `mediastore'. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediastore